# How to transpose a table in an R markdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose I print a data frame called summary_table as follows:

```
summary_table = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(11,12,13),c=c(21,22,23),d=c(31,32,33),e=c(41,42,43),f=c(51,52,53),g=c(61,62,63),h=c(71,72,73),i=c(81,82,83),j=c(91,92,93),k=c(101,102,103),l=c(111,112,113))

print(xtable(summary_table,
         align=rep("r",13),
         caption="A summary of stuff."),
  table.placement="H")
```

Now suppose summary_table has only three rows, but twelve columns.  I'd like to flip (transpose) the table so that the columns become rows.

Any easy way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using the `t()` function:

```
print(xtable(t(summary_table),
         align=rep("r",4),
         caption="A summary of stuff."),
  table.placement="H")
```

Your example is not reproducible, so I cannot test it.

Comment: This solution works with (r,4).  Change and I will accept.  Thanks!