# Using groups as table header in kableExtra

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I recently discovered `kableExtra`. Making tables in R instead of manually entering values in a Word-table is much faster and less prone to error.

I want to make tables that have a (or several) grouping variable(s) as a header.
Basically, instead of this

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length), sd = sd(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  kbl(digits = 1,format = "pipe")

|Species    | mean|  sd|
|:----------|----:|---:|
|setosa     |  5.0| 0.4|
|versicolor |  5.9| 0.5|
|virginica  |  6.6| 0.6|
```

Instead I want to accomplish this, or a variation of this.

```
|      | Setosa | Versicolor | Virginica |   |
|------|--------|------------|-----------|---|
| mean | 5.0    | 5.9        | 6.6       |   |
| sd   | 0.4    | 0.5        | 0.5       |   |
|      |        |            |           |   |
```

For multiple headers, I was thinking something in the lines of this

```
iris %>%
  mutate(long = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5,TRUE,FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(Species,long) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length), sd = sd(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  kbl(digits = 1)

|Species    |long  | mean|  sd|
|:----------|:-----|----:|---:|
|setosa     |FALSE |  4.8| 0.2|
|setosa     |TRUE  |  5.3| 0.2|
|versicolor |FALSE |  5.0| 0.1|
|versicolor |TRUE  |  6.0| 0.5|
|virginica  |FALSE |  4.9|  NA|
|virginica  |TRUE  |  6.6| 0.6|
```

But instead producing

```
|      | Setosa | Setosa | Versicolor | Versicolor | Virginica | Virginica |   |
|------|--------|--------|------------|------------|-----------|-----------|---|
| long | TRUE   | FALSE  | TRUE       | FALSE      | TRUE      | FALSE     |   |
| mean | 5.3    | 4.8    | 6.0        | 5.0        | 6.6       | 4.9       |   |
| sd   | 0.2    | 0.2    | 0.5        | 0.1        | 0.6       | NA        |   |
|      |        |        |            |            |           |           |   |
```

Bonus points for not repeating the table header, but having a merged cell.

Can anyone point me to any examples or relevant documentation?

I am using `R 4.0.2`, and as such only have access to `kableExtra`, not `kable`.

Comment: How about using the transpose function `t()`?

Comment: I'm not aware of that function, @holzben, can you elaborate?

Comment: It's the normal matrix transpose function, I thougt it might help to transpose the the data first and dan use `kableExtra`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848622/how-to-transpose-a-table-in-an-r-markdown-document

Comment: Also take a look at `add_header_above` [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#Grouped_Columns__Rows) for having a header than spans multiple columns.